# Grepl like match to extract specific/exact string in R

Tags: r

I have my string variable as:

```
column.types <- c("CC_0", "CC_25", "CC_50", "CC_75", "CC_100", "CCS_0", "CCS_25", 
"CCS_50", "CCS_75", "CCS_100", "CS_0", "CS_25", "CS_50", "CS_75", 
"CS_100", "SCS_0", "SCS_25", "SCS_50", "SCS_75", "SCS_100")
```

pattern I want to search:

```
Type <- "CC"
```

Result I want:

```
"CC_0"    "CC_25"   "CC_50"   "CC_75"   "CC_100"
```

Code I tried:

```
column.types[grepl(Type, column.types)]
```

which gives me undesired  `column.types ("CCS_0"   "CCS_25"  "CCS_50"  "CCS_75"  "CCS_100")`

I want to use this in a loop, so use of negation wouldn't work. So, what should I use here?

Answer (score 3):

An option is to specify the delimiter to avoid any non-specific matches

```
grep(paste0("^", Type,  "_\\d+$"), column.types, value = TRUE)
#[1] "CC_0"   "CC_25"  "CC_50"  "CC_75"  "CC_100"
```

Here, the `pattern` is created by `paste`ing the `^` (specifying the start of the string), followed by the characters ('CC'), then the underscore (`_`) and one or more digits (`\\d+`) until the end (`$`) of the string